What is the correct python version to install inltk library
I am trying to install inltk library for my project
https://inltk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_docs.html
I am using windows.
The installation page tells us to install tourch 1.3.1.
pip install torch==1.3.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
The maximum Python version to install Touch 1.3.1 is Python 3.7.
I also have to install inltk:
pip install inltk
This needs a much higher Python version like 3.10 and above.
How do I solve this problem?

The link in your post says "inltk is currently supported with ... Python >= 3.6"

yes but the maximum phython version to install tourch 1.3.1 is python 3.7

If it is true that the MAXIMUM Python version compatible with torch 1.3.1 is Python 3.7, as you say that it is, then you should should Python version 3.7, which is also compatible with inltk, since 3.7 >= 3.6.

To install inltk, you'll need Python 3.6 or later.This is because inltk is built on top of several other libraries that require Python 3.6 or newer.
Install Python 3.6 or later:https://www.python.org/downloads/
Install pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/
Install inltk: Open a terminal or command prompt and run the following command:
pip install inltk

